# PHP: Default /tmp sessions VS session_set_save_handler() performance

Tags: php, database, performance, session

During my research I have found opinions pointing in both directions on this issue. A discussion would be appreciated to clarify this issue.

We are aware of the obvious advantageous security aspects on storing the session data in the database.

**Option 1:**

> Using the default session storage on the filesystem (defaults to /tmp)

**Option 2:**

> Using [session_set_save_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to
>   store the session data in the/a
>   database.

---

**My questions are:**

1. On a high traffic site, what example would give the best performance?
2. Is this a matter of system hardware and where the current bottlenecks on this specific site are? In this case, the site is heavily pointed toward displaying specific user data from the database. Possibly this would be a question in need of serverfault input.
3. The site will probably have to propagate on to multiple servers soon, to deal with load and accessibility from other parts of the world. Think CDN. Does this affect my decision? I'm thinking it would be much easier to manage session information between the different computers if it is stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why storing to /tmp isn't favored on high traffic sites is because they use load balancing. Load balancing effectively swaps which machine delivers the data. If the session is in /tmp, not all machines have the same /tmp directory which means your users might start appearing logged in or logged out for no apparent reason.

That's why some sites store data in databases. However, that's ineffective as every request to the site means pulling info from db, which means connecting constantly, transforming data from text to an array and so on.

So, there's the third option - store the session data with Memcache. It's really easy, and if you google-fu a bit about this, you'll find answers and you can set the whole thing up in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: The load balancer could choose the machine due to the session ID.

Comment: It's not just the load balancing, I used that as an example. There are other things with session being saved in /tmp, such as anyone who has access to the machine can tamper with session files and so on. This was a question about performance and storing data directly to RAM is the fastest way to deal with session storage / retrieval.